# how to add type declaration to react-typescript project with CRA

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, type-declaration, react-tsx

I have created a react typescript project with CRA with the command `yarn create react-app my-app --typescript`

now I have a module `foo` installed that does not have any typing not by default, not in defentlytyped repository.

i.e. in a component, I have

```
import {bar} from 'foo';
```

which throws error `Type error: Could not find a declaration file for module 'foo'. '/*/node_modules/foo/dist/entry.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

I created `foo.d.ts` in types folder at the root of the project like

```
declare module 'foo'{ import * as React from 'react' }
```

just to have the `foo` as type `any` but still, get the same error. it seems that whatever compiler (webpack,other transpiler) does not find the declaration at `types` folder

how can I add custom type declaration to the project?

Comment: have you try the following format in your foo.d.ts? 'export function foo() {...};'

Comment: and what do you mean by that? an implementation for foo? @ChrisChen

Answer (score 1):

Here is a real use-case example. 
I managed to integrate [kendo-ui-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kendo-ui-core) into CRA+Typescript.

The problem was that there are no typings for kendo-ui-core, namely the typings have a different name: [@types/kendo-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/kendo-ui)

Typescript was complaining about not having type definitions

[image: VS Code complaining about missing declaration]

To resolve the issue, create a file called **kendo-ui-core.d.ts** in your **/src** directory with the following contents:

```
// src/kendo-ui-core.d.ts
declare module 'kendo-ui-core' {
  import * as KendoTypings from '@types/kendo-ui';
  export = KendoTypings;
}
```

Comment: do we need to add the `kendo-ui-core.d.ts` in a specific folder like `src/@types` and then add that folder to `tsconfig`?

Answer (score -2):

This works:

```
/* create src/CustomTypes.ts */

namespace MyCustomType {
  export type foo = number;
}

export default MyCustomType;
```

use like this:

```
import MyCustomType from "src/CustomTypes";

const num: MyCustomType.foo = 123;
```

Comment: Would  love to see some arguments by those who downvoted the answer

Comment: @idleberg It's not the TS definition for the `foo` library.